# pass value from ashx to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, ashx

I have written the fallowing ashx code. for **autocomplete textbox**.

i want to transfer the values `ContactId`, `ContactName` from **ashx to code behind** in aspx file.
how can i do that

**code for ashx file**

```
 <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search_CS" %>

  using System;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Text;

  public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select ContactId, ContactName from Customers where " +
            "ContactName like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["ContactName"])
                        .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**code for aspx file**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx');
});      
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**in aspx page**

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_look_suggs(key, cont) {
            var script_name = 'Search_CS.ashx';
            var params = { 'q': $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").val() }
            $.get(script_name, params,
     function (obj) {
         // obj is just array of strings
         var res = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

             res.push({ id: i, value: obj[i].Name });
         }
         // will build suggestions list
         cont(res);
     },
     'json');
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete({ ajax_get: get_look_suggs });

        });



    </script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

**in handler**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;

public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler
{
    private readonly JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public class names
    {


        public names(string p)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.Name = p;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    // Handle request based on method

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select ContactId, ContactName from Customers where " +
                "ContactName like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                List<names> lstnew = new List<names>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        lstnew.Add(new names(sdr["ContactName"].ToString()));

                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                string jsonObj = js.Serialize(lstnew);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"files.json\"");
                context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
        }
    }


}
```